# KeyInformation parameter of NtEnumerateKey()

Tags: c++, c, windows, delphi, winapi

I'm curious to know how the `KeyInformation` parameter should be passed to `NtEnumerateKey()`. When I run the following code, `NtEnumerateKey()` returns `NTSTATUS = 0xC000000D` with the error message *"An invalid parameter was passed to a service or function."*

I'm using Windows 7. Although the following code uses Delphi language, you can answer my question in C language too. My question is not specific to a programming language.

```
type
  KEY_NAME_INFORMATION = record
    NameLength: ULONG;
    Name: array[0..254] of WCHAR;
  end;
  PKEY_NAME_INFORMATION = ^KEY_NAME_INFORMATION;

var
  iNtStatus: LONG;
  hKeyResult: THandle;
  KeyNameInfo: KEY_NAME_INFORMATION;
  iResultLen: ULONG;

iNtStatus := NtOpenKey(@hKeyResult, (KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS) and not
    SYNCHRONIZE, @rObjAttrs);
if hKeyResult = 0 then Exit;

iNtStatus := NtEnumerateKey(hKeyResult,
    0,
    KeyNameInformation,
    @KeyNameInfo,                 // I'm asking about this parameter,
    SizeOf(KEY_NAME_INFORMATION), // and also this parameter
    @iResultLen);
```

### UPDATED: Weird Thing

If I pass `KeyBasicInformation` instead of `KeyNameInformation`, `NtEnumerateKey()` returns `STATUS_SUCCESS`. Does not `NtEnumerateKey()` support the `KeyNameInformation`?

```
type
  KEY_BASIC_INFORMATION = record
    LastWriteTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
    TitleIndex: ULONG;
    NameLength: ULONG;
    Name: array[0..254] of WCHAR;
  end;
  PKEY_BASIC_INFORMATION = ^KEY_BASIC_INFORMATION;

var
  KeyBasicInfo: KEY_BASIC_INFORMATION;

iNtStatus := NtEnumerateKey(hKeyResult,
    0,
    KeyBasicInformation,           // Note this!
    @KeyBasicInfo,                 // Note this!
    SizeOf(KEY_BASIC_INFORMATION), // Note this!
    @iResultLen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of Zw(Nt for usermode)EnumerateKey you'll see

```
NTSTATUS ZwEnumerateKey(
  _In_       HANDLE KeyHandle,
  _In_       ULONG Index,
  _In_       KEY_INFORMATION_CLASS KeyInformationClass,
  _Out_opt_  PVOID KeyInformation,
  _In_       ULONG Length,
  _Out_      PULONG ResultLength
);
```

Then if you look down at KeyInformationClass you'll see

```
KeyInformationClass [in]
Specifies a KEY_INFORMATION_CLASS enumeration value that determines the type of information to be received by the KeyInformation buffer. Set KeyInformationClass to one of the following values:
KeyBasicInformation
KeyFullInformation
KeyNodeInformation
If any value not in this list is specified, the routine returns error code STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER.
```

You need to be using one of those 3

Comment: Yes, but the `KEY_INFORMATION_CLASS` is an enumeration type. When the `KeyInformationClass` parameter is set to `KeyNameInformation`, the next parameter (`KeyInformation`) must be a pointer to a variable of type `KEY_NAME_INFORMATION` structure.

Comment: @Astaroth I've changed my answer

Comment: Oops, how hasty I was, to not read the text you quote. Thanks @MMavipc.